# Why there is a error message Exception: This file is already closed

Tags: python, io, whoosh

1.I was trying to write a python code to get all contents of files in each subfolder and create a index for each content (file contents). All the contents for each file can be get successfully. However, when I run the code, it always shows an error message Exception: This file is already closed.

2.Here is the code for building an index for each content, could someone explain to me why this thing could happened?
The traceback:

```
python-input-49-38a47b2f8c0c> in <module>
     39 print(searcher)
     40 
---> 41 writers.commit(optimize=True)
     42 
     43 # from whoosh.query import *

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/whoosh/writing.py in commit(self, mergetype, optimize, merge)
    928         else:
    929             # Close segment files
--> 930             self._close_segment()
    931         # Write TOC
    932         self._commit_toc(finalsegments)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/whoosh/writing.py in _close_segment(self)
    841     def _close_segment(self):
    842         if not self.perdocwriter.is_closed:
--> 843             self.perdocwriter.close()
    844         if not self.fieldwriter.is_closed:
    845             self.fieldwriter.close()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/whoosh/codec/whoosh3.py in close(self)
    265         for writer in self._colwriters.values():
    266             writer.finish(self._doccount)
--> 267         self._cols.save_as_files(self._storage, self._column_filename)
    268 
    269         # If vectors were written, close the vector writers

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/whoosh/filedb/compound.py in save_as_files(self, storage, name_fn)
    295 
    296     def save_as_files(self, storage, name_fn):
--> 297         for name, blocks in self._readback():
    298             f = storage.create_file(name_fn(name))
    299             for block in blocks():

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/whoosh/filedb/compound.py in _readback(self)
    276 
    277             yield (name, gen)
--> 278         temp.close()
    279         self._tempstorage.delete_file(self._tempname)
    280 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/whoosh/filedb/structfile.py in close(self)
    121 
    122         if self.is_closed:
--> 123             raise Exception("This file is already closed")
    124         if self.onclose:
    125             self.onclose(self)
```

Exception: This file is already closed

```py
    import os
    import codecs

    import whoosh
    from whoosh.index import create_in
    from whoosh.fields import *
    from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
    
    
    
    schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), path=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT,textdata=TEXT(stored=True))
    
    ix = create_in("folder", schema)
    filelist = []
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./test_result"):
        for file in files:
            #append the file name to the list
            filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))
    
    #print all the file names
    
    writer = ix.writer()
    i = 0
    
    for name in filelist:
          
        i = i +1
        with codecs.open (name, "r",encoding='utf-8',
                     errors='ignore') as myfile:
            text=myfile.read()
    #         print ("adding document "+name)
            writer.add_document(title="document "+name, path="folder",content=text,textdata=text)
            myfile.close()
            print(text)
            
        
    
    searcher = ix.searcher()
    print(searcher)
    
    writers.commit(optimize=True)
```

Comment: Closing a file object twice is totally fine, though - `close` is idempotent. Double closes shouldn't raise an error. (This isn't the case at OS level, but it's handled by the file object.)

Comment: I just delete myfile.close(), but it still shows the error message. I don't know why this still happened

Comment: Please post the complete traceback

Comment: I just provide the traceback information please check it

Answer (score 0):

`with` statement handles resources management, including file closing. You could read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/).

This code:

```
f = open(file)
f.write("blablabla")
f.close
```

is equivalent to this:

```
with open(file) as f
    f.write("blablabla")
```

This exception is a result of you trying to close a file that is already closed implicitly by `with` statement.

You only need to delete this line:

```
myfile.close()
```

EDIT:

I just explained the error in the code, but didn't notice the update in the comments. Please update the question itself with the mentioned line deleted.

On a side note, I see you used `writers.commit(`) instead of `writer.commit()`, please make sure it's not a typo and update your question if your code still doesn't work.